# Conditionally perform or do not perform a wrapping if

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I need a little help.
How can I write this code more properly?

```
function myFunc(performCheck = true) {
  if (performCheck) {
    if (b === a) {
      mySecondMethod();
    }
  } else {
    mySecondMethod();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this one?

Comment: This code make little sense to me. What are you trying to achieve? Actually since you set performCheck to true the outer else will never be triggered

Comment: performCheck is set to true only if a method myFunc is called without passing performCheck argument.

Comment: @Rayon It just looks like it's not a good piece of code. Looking at this, I just know it can be done better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a single expression and check if not the first part or the second.

```
function myFunc(performCheck = true) {
    if (!performCheck || b === a)) mySecondMethod();
}
```

Comment: Of course, a good  anwer.. Now I'm a little shamed. I guess my mind just had a break.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!performCheck || b === a) { secondMethod() }
```

Comment: Yes. That is a good anwer. I think my mind was a little blank while making this code..